# How to distinct servers in a REST environment?

Tags: php, rest, authentication, websocket

I want to distinct servers from a REST API.

I have a REST api, a WebSocket and X local servers (The amount change every minutes, from 1 to 20).

The REST api and the websocket are both in php, while local servers are in Java.

The servers are all connected to the websocket. So they can communicate between them.

The servers and the websocket can send requests to the REST api.

The problem is, I want to allow anybody to send requests to the REST server.

So, I have to authenticate the websocket and the servers through REST server to allow some actions (for example create users) to the WebSocket and others actions (for example login) to servers.

All these servers are on the same machine (==> localhost).

Do you have any ideas how can I authenticate servers and WebSocket ? I think that OAuth2 is good only for other users (Not WebSocket and not Java Servers).

I don't know if private and public keys are good in this situation, if yes, how can I use it ? Or maybe I have to create different passwords for WebSocket and all Java servers ?

Thanks,
0ddlyoko

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OAuth2 can still be a good idea. You will not be able to use the `Bearer` HTTP header, because there are no real HTTP headers in Websockets, but you can still send that token over to authenticate.

Having one standard way to handle authentication is a good thing.

Comment: Thanks for your help, after some searches, there is different authentication ways: **Client Credentials**, **Authorization Code Grant**, **User Credentials** and **Implicit Grant**.

In my case, Is Client Credentials better for WebSocket to communicate with the REST api ? (With Refresh Token)

If the WebSocket creates new Client for the OAuth2 (then send the access_token to the Java Server that want to communicate with the REST server), is it a good idea? (==> one access_token per Java servers) or is it better to use one single access_token for all Java servers?

Comment: Which grant you need has nothing to do with your server-side scenario or protocol. The important part is the trust model. Who trusts who? Do you have third parties or do you control every client? Do you have users at all? Is it a browser or another server authenticating? Answers to those questions dictate the grant type

Comment: Here's a guide that may help: https://aaronparecki.com/oauth-2-simplified/